# php files are not executing but downloading

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, php-7

I am trying to configure LAMP in my Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop with PHP 7.0, Apache2, and MySQL.

Everything seems to be working but when i try to execute any php file by putting it on path (`/var/www/html`), the file gets downloaded.

Below are the commands which are already looked up and tried, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Am I missing anything?
Please let me know any suggestions or advice will be very appreciated.

Comment: did you `a2enmod php` (or maybe a2enmod php7) and restart after then? Is your php-code surrounded by <?php, not only <? (important if short_open_tag is false in your config)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is distro specific, but (assuming you are using Apache 2.4) there are some additional steps you might look into.

First, in your httpd.conf file, look for: "LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so" and COMMENT that out.

The next line "#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so" should be UNCOMMENTED.

Then, add this include at the end of the file: "Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf"

Restart Apache and you should be up and running.